# Allow mjs extension files in React with typescript and craco

Tags: reactjs, typescript, craco

I have a basic react app with Craco for tailwindcss support. What I'm trying to do is read from a main.mjs file but when I try to import the file, I run into a ts2307 error that module cannot be found. Is there a way for me to get app to find *.mjs files? Like I have tried going through the craco config documentation but I keep missing the point I guess.

Answer (score 2):

in your `craco.config.js` file, need to allow tailwind css as well as overwrite webpack configuration as below.

```
module.exports = {
  style: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
    },
  },
  webpack: {
    configure: {
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            type: 'javascript/auto',
            test: /\.mjs$/,
            use: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
};
```